# How to convert a const char * to std::string

Tags: c++

What is the correct/best/simplest way to convert a c-style string to a std::string.

The conversion should accept a max_length, and terminate the string at the first \0 char, if this occur before max_length charter.

Comment: Use the constructor.

Comment: If I use the constructor like std::string s(c_sting, lenght) it will end the string at the first occurrence of \0

Comment: or assignment works too, depending on lifetime of the recipient.

Comment: @Allan: Then use the other constructor that takes a pointer to a null-terminated string :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This page on [`string::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) gives two potential constructors that would do what you want:

```
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos );
```

Example:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char* p= (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p, "Hello world");

    string s(p, 15);
    cout << s.size() << ":[" << s << "]" << endl;
    string t(p, 0, 15);
    cout << t.size() << ":[" << t << "]" << endl;

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
15:[Hello world]
11:[Hello world]
```

The first form considers `p` to be a simple array, and so will create (in our case) a string of length 15, which however prints as a 11-character null-terminated string with `cout << ...`. Probably not what you're looking for.

The second form will implicitly convert the `char*` to a string, and then keep the maximum between its length and the `n` you specify. I think this is the simplest solution, in terms of what you have to write.

Comment: calloc + delete???

Comment: fair enough, fixed :)

Comment: Well, not C++-ish either, but okay.

Answer (score 14):

```
std::string str(c_str, strnlen(c_str, max_length));
```

---

At [Christian Rau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743214)'s request:

`strnlen` is specified in [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strnlen.html) and available in GNU's [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html) and the [Microsoft run-time library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh.aspx).  It is not yet found in some other systems; you may fall back to [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnulib/manual/html_node/strnlen.html)'s substitute.

Comment: Is `strnlen` a standard C++ function? If not, you should mention this non-portability.

Comment: @ChristianRau: It is a POSIX standard function, but not universally available.  I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::string the_string(c_string);
if(the_string.size() > max_length)
    the_string.resize(max_length);
```

Comment: What if c_string is not properly NULL-terminated?

Comment: C-style strings should always be NULL terminated.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually trickier than it looks, because you can't call `strlen`
*unless* the string is actually nul terminated.  In fact, without some
additional constraints, the problem practically requires inventing a new
function, a version of `strlen` which never goes beyond the a certain
length.  However:

If the buffer containing the c-style string is guaranteed to be at least
`max_length` char's (although perhaps with a `'\0'` before the end), 
then you can use the address-length constructor of `std::string`, and
trim afterwards:

```
std::string result( c_string, max_length );
result.erase( std::find( result.begin(), result.end(), '\0' ), result.end() );
```

and if you know that `c_string` is a nul terminated string (but perhaps
longer than `max_length`, you can use `strlen`:

```
std::string result( c_string, std::min( strlen( c_string ), max_length ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a constructor accepting two pointer parameters, so the code is simply

```
 std::string cppstr(cstr, cstr + min(max_length, strlen(cstr)));
```

this is also going to be as efficient as `std::string cppstr(cstr)` if the length is smaller than `max_length`.

Comment: You could also use the constructor taking a pointer and a length, no need for the pointer arithmetic (though it won't be much different). And technically it doesn't take two pointer parameters, but two iterator parameters. And by the way, it won't be as efficient, as it is O(2n) instead of O(n) and constants matter, but it's of course still a correct solution.

Comment: @ChristianRau: One scan is necessary with a C string to know the length (how much to allocate) but there's no need for a second one (the constructor could just subtract two pointers to get the size). So there is one scan for length and one scan for copy: this is the minimum you can do unless you accept wasting space.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is this constructor:
`std::string ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n = npos )`, passing pos as 0. Your const char* c-style string will get implicitly cast to const string for the first parameter.

```
const char *c_style = "012abd";
std::string cpp_style = std::string(c_style, 0, 10);
```

UPDATE: removed the "new" from the `cpp_style` initialization

Comment: I am not the down-voter but the operator new is completely redundant in this case, stack allocation is fine for the std::string (it smells too much like Java).

Comment: fixed the use of `new`