# Converting string to const* char

Tags: c++, string

I have two `string` declarations:

1. `killerName`
2. `victimName`

I need to convert these two string values to const* char.

Example of how I use my method:

```
if (killer.IsRealPlayer) {
   killerName = killer.GetName(); -- need to convert to const* char
   victimName = victim.GetName(); -- need to convert to const* char

   Notice(killerName + "has slain:" + victimName, killer.GetMapIndex(), false); 
}
```

Some error I receive:

> Error  111 error C2664: 'Notice' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const char */

Comment: Your error message says the opposite of your question.

Comment: This is really unclear. The output and code do not match your question or title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126498/how-to-convert-a-const-char-to-stdstring

Comment: Yeah... my bad.. i will edit it in few seconds. Sorry

Comment: And your new edit is completely off-target.  Do you know what happens if you do `const char*` + `"has slain:"` + `const char*` ?

Comment: How about downloading the the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a std::string to const char\* or char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that function `Notice` have the first parameter of type `const char *` However the expression passed to it as the first argument

```
killerName + "has slain:" + victimName
```

has type `std::string`

Simply call the function the following way

```
Notice( ( killerName + "has slain:" + victimName ).c_str(), killer.GetMapIndex(), false);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Notice(string(killerName + "has slain:" + victimName).c_str(), killer.GetMapIndex(), false);
```

`std::string::c_str()` gives the `const char*` to the buffer.  I think that's what you want.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 1):

As others already wrote, the result of `killerName + "has slain:" + victimName` is of type `std::string`. So, if your `Notice()` function expects a `const char*` as first parameter, you must convert from `std::string` to `const char*`, and since there is no *implicit* conversion defined for `std::string`, you must call the `std::string::c_str()` method:

```
Notice((killerName + "has slain:" + victimName).c_str(), killer.GetMapIndex(), false);
```

However, I'd like to ask: why do you have `Notice()` expecting a `const char*` as first parameter?
Would it be better to just use `const std::string&`? In general, in modern C++ code, you may want to use string classes like `std::string` instead of raw `char*` pointers.

(Another option would be to have two overloads of `Notice()`: one expecting a `const std::string&` as first parameter, and the other one expecting a `const char*`, if for some reason the `const char*` version does make sense in your particular context; this double overload pattern is used e.g. in the `std::fstream` constructor.)